# Import external .py script

Tags: python, scripting

I have a Blender python script in my Blender file

```
import bpy
print(variable)
```

and an external .py file in the same directory as the .blend file.

```
variable = "spam"
```

I want to import the external file into Blender using a relative path.

Comment: Please add more details to your question, it is currently unclear what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

You can append the path to your script

```
import bpy, sys
sys.path.append('//myscript.py')
import myscript
```

Comment: The second file is not in the blend file but in the same directory as the blend file

Comment: This code is for if the script is in the same directory as the script calling it. Is that not the case?

Comment: no, because it is in the same directory as the .blend file but not IN the .blend file

Comment: Edited my answer.